# Calculating the length of an object

Tags: javascript

How is the length of an object calculated?

```
console.log({0:"a",1:"b"}.length)//returns undefined but object has the length property


Object.hasOwnProperty("length") // true
```

But how can hasOwnProperty() work?Object dont have this method ,the method is in its prototype

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).length`

Comment: FYI, `Object.hasOwnProperty("length")` returns `true` because `Object` is a **function**, [and functions have a `length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length). The object you created does not have a `.length` property nor does it inherit one (`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('length') === false`).

Comment: @elclanrs No sir ,i dont want that ,i want to use length property here {}.length

Comment: @Felix Kling great thanks ,i was confuse by the name Object and forgot that it is also a function

Comment: @Maizere: `{}` doesn't have a `.length`. `Object` (the constructor) has. Try `console.log({0:"a",1:"b"}.hasOwnProperty("length"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Object.keys({0:"a",1:"b"}).length;
```